# Azure Devops Release for application that remains the same except for appsettings.json

Tags: json, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I am creating an Azure devops build pipeline and release. This release has a staging environment that utilizes a deployment group with 3 servers, in production it can have 50+ servers. The application will be the same across all the servers except for the appsettings file. appsettings will contain the db connections and location/server specific variables. I have looked into ways to manipulate this file on release per server, all I have come across are ways to have variable substitutions in the release for environments when you only need to switch values in a dev to staging to prod release. Is there a good way to manipulate this file per server in a deployment group rather than 50+ stages/tags, or a better way to setup my pipe and release?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a good way to manipulate this file per server in a deployment
> group rather than 50+ stages/tags

Afraid to say that as far as I know, we does not support this possible yet. But the if you host your app on Azure website, azure have one [new feature](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-app-configuration-is-now-generally-available/) can achieve this goal.

But if you host the app to self servers, I'm afraid that the better deployment approach in this scenario is **Build once, deploy many**. In another word, build the project in Build pipeline, and configure corresponding appsettings.json file on specific stage.

To improving the maintainability of the release and simplifying the configuration structure, you can make use of [task group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=azure-devops) and the [variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic). (Please keeping using **variable substitutions** in release)

**Encapsulate** a sequence of reusable tasks into task group, then this template will be used in every deployment group job. *Note, you can make the reusable parameters as a part of template.* Just **abstract** the app setting information and store them as variables into corresponding variable group.

At this moment, whenever you add a new server, you only need to save the corresponding app setting parameters into the created variable group. In release pipeline, you only need to add task group, and link the previous created variable group to specified stage. Execute the release pipeline, then everything will go as expect.

In post-maintenance, you just need to modify the basic configuration of deploy task task once, and it can be applied to all stages. When you need to modify the corresponding server app setting configuration, you can modify them by opening the corresponding variable group.